# interpreting JSON with PHP and putting it in array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have only worked with JSON once before, but I don't recall how to use it with PHP.

If I have a script that returns JSON like this:

```
{
  "bunisess":[
    "business",
    "bonuses",
    "burnooses",
    "boniness",
    "burnoose's"
  ]
}
```

how can I take that and make each value a value in a PHP array. The keys just being numbers from 0 onwards?

Comment: What all of us do when not recalling something is googling it. Typing "php json" into the search box is not hard to do.

Comment: Go to http://php.net, type "json" in the search box, and submit...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use json_decode, but pass true as the second parameter to get an associative array back:

```
$json='{"bunisess":["business","bonuses","burnooses","boniness","burnoose\'s"]}';

$data=json_decode($json, true);
```

Now, you can use array_values to get a numerically indexed array as you required:

```
$data=array_values($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple google search could have lead you to this page : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.json-decode.php

The subarray will be respecting exatcly what you're asking for.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `$data` is the complete JSON string

```
$stdObject = json_decode($data, true);

print_r($array);
```

You should get an array with one key `bunisess` and value another numeric array with the other values.